# no "word wrapping" in django-admin display

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

So I defined models.py like this:

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.country+"-"+self.zipcode+" "+self.city+", "+self.name+", "+self.street
```

and I am using it in admin.py like this with "venue" as ForeignKey

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["date_begin", "date_end", "speaker", "description", "venue"]
```

Everything works fine but in the admin-display every string is automatically word-wrapped except the "venue" which is only one line. And it takes up most of the space as it is rather long and other strings have to be wrapped in like 3-4 lines.

Can I change it so that the "venu"-string is also automatically wrapped in 2-3 lines if it is too long?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the css property `word-wrap: break-word;`. Otherwise, you can write a python function to split the word up by inserting space characters if the string is over a certain length.